# ido-find-file on windows 7 does not use system tool

Tags: windows, emacs, ido

I would like `ido-find-file` to open pdf files with the default programm on Win7. I am aware of `ido-default-file-method` but there is no customization option that would allow that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the excelent `openwith` library.

https://bitbucket.org/jpkotta/openwith/overview